# How to Generate Custom JSESSIONID to avoid conflict

Tags: java, glassfish, session-cookies, jsessionid

I have two application deployed in single glassfish server with 2 different domains(port 8080,9090) with same context path. Its creating issue when two application are open in single browser with in different tabs.What i found is due to `JSESSIONID` are getting interchange. Is there a way to avoid or generate `JSESSIONID` specific to application?

Note: i didn't find any solution . I am using glassfish,servlet 2.3 api.

Comment: @EJB what i understood from the above post, the are 2 application which generate the different JSESSIONID but getting swap while swithing the tabs.In this case how to rename the JSESSIONID cookieName to avoid exchanging?

Comment: yes sarun you are correct..in my case its generating the unique JSESSIONID but while switching the tabs JSESSIONID is getting swap ..how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manage to solve the above issue by generating Unique JSESSIONID name for both application

Added cookie-config under session-config

```
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
    <name>JSESSIONID_APPLICATION_NAME</name><!-- default is jsessionid -->
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```

with the above configuration, application will have unique jsessionid name example : `JSESSIONID_APP1:xybo89aoa3fhjasdf ,JSESSIONID_APP2:abc1234hjadkf`